# Meteor Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, database, meteor

I have followed well the instruction of meteor.com but i got this error. i itry also to change it into **template.registerhelper** but it seems that no output response.

> main.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
>       at main.js (main.js:8)
>       at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
>       at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
>       at app.js?hash=08534f7c8c7b3f0963300e61b8d521d38ce05c92:90

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import './main.html';

PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.main.helpers({ "player" : function(){
         return PlayersList.find();
     },
 });
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
 Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{> hello}}

<ul>
    {{#each player}}
        <li>{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul> 

</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>LeaderBoard</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: You do not have a template called "main" you only have "hello"

Comment: @Salketer looks like OP is doing it kinda right ~ https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

Comment: @Phil do you really think that he is doing it right if he gets an error? On the link you provide, the helper is applied on Template.body, which exists... Not on Template.main

Comment: its my first doing this. can someone help me

Comment: @Salketer I meant as far as the tutorial goes. The tute shows a single HTML file named `body.html` that has `<template name="tasks">`. I don't think the template tag is the issue

Comment: @Phil, Template.body targets the body of the page. Template.tasks would target the Tasks template, and Template.main will target the main template. But only if one exists.

Comment: Just to be clear, the name of the file has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic line is `Template.main.helpers` as hinted by the error message.

This happens because you do not have a `main` template. Either create one with the html you want, it should be inside a `<Template>` tag:

```
<Template name="main">
<!-- HTML -->
</Template>
```

Or you can change the Template you are targeting to `Template.body` since the helper you are using is currently located in your body.

Relevant tutorial part:

> Everything inside  tags is compiled into Meteor templates,
>   which can be included inside HTML with {{> templateName}} or
>   referenced in your JavaScript with Template.templateName. Also, the
>   body section can be referenced in your JavaScript with Template.body.
>   Think of it as a special "parent" template, that can include the other
>   child templates.